# How to make a string into array of characters?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, string

I'm trying to split a user input string into array of characters to count the number of occurrence of each character. Below is my code

```
input=input()
list=input.split()
print(list)
```

when i input string `aaasssfffgggg` it gave the output `['aaasssfffgggg']`
.But i need it as a array of characters

Comment: I can't test rn but `list(inp)` should give the right result. Also don't name the variable `input`; you are overwriting the function

Comment: Note that an [`array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) in Python is not the same thing as a `list`.

Answer (score 1):

## Use `list()`

```
my_string = 'hello'
l = list(my_string)
# ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

Comment: It works :) .Thank you so much